# Why am failing to select radio button using selenium webdriver?

Tags: javascript, java, html, selenium-webdriver

OS: Windows 7
Selenium Version: 3.3.1,
Browser: Firefox
Browser Version: 47.0.2 (64-bit)

```
Html Code:



       <div class="radio">
<input id="passwordRadios1" class="password-radio" type="radio" value="guest" name="passwordRadios">
<input type="hidden" value=" " name="_D:passwordRadios">
<label for="passwordRadios1"> No (you can save your details later)</label>
</div>
<div class="form-inline">
<div class="radio">
<input id="passwordRadios2" class="password-radio" type="radio" value="register" name="passwordRadios">
<input type="hidden" value=" " name="_D:passwordRadios">
<label class="radio-inline" for="passwordRadios2">Yes, my password is:</label>
</div>
```

while am trying to select first radio button am failing using `cssSelector`,`xpath` and all locators

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#passwordRadios1")).click();
```

> Error

```
Test Failed
2
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Element <input name="passwordRadios" id="passwordRadios1" class="password-radio" value="guest" type="radio"> is not clickable at point (168, 431.83331298828125). Other element would receive the click: <div class="loader-overlay" style="opacity:0.9;"></div>
Command duration or timeout: 560 milliseconds
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: '5234b32', time: '2017-03-10 09:00:17 -0800'
System info: host: 'TWVEN-DES-05', ip: '172.16.24.53', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_121'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=true, rotatable=false, handlesAlerts=true, databaseEnabled=true, version=47.0.2, platform=WINDOWS, nativeEvents=false, acceptSslCerts=true, webStorageEnabled=true, locationContextEnabled=true, browserName=firefox, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]
Session ID: a692e880-f284-47af-9a20-1bcf60d76e63
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:216)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:168)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:638)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:274)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.click(RemoteWebElement.java:84)
    at tesPack.Test1Class.main(Test1Class.java:76)
```

Could anyone please help me...

Comment: why are you doing `By.cssSelector` and passing the id in it? shouldnt it be `driver.findElement(By.id("#passwordRadios1")).click(); ` ?

Comment: i copied this CSSselector using firepath :-(

Comment: i see, https://loadfocus.com/blog/2013/09/05/how-to-locate-web-elements-with-selenium-webdriver/ this is a decent referral

Comment: so changing from `cssSelector` to `id` didnt solve the issue?

Comment: no..didn't solved..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this below code.

```
driver.get("file:///C:/Users/Jainish.M.Kapadia/Desktop/aaa.html");
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

driver.findElement(By.id("inputEmail")).sendKeys("test@gmail.com");

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 7);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='passwordRadios1']"))));

WebElement no = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='passwordRadios1']"));
if(!no.isSelected())
{
    no.click();
}
```

Comment: Which error you get? Can you please pass error. I tried same code on my end on different browsers and it gets run successfully without showing any error.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Element <input name="passwordRadios" id="passwordRadios1" class="password-radio" value="guest" type="radio"> is not clickable at point (168, 431.83331298828125). Other element would receive the click: <div class="loader-overlay" style="opacity:0.9;"></div>
Command duration or timeout: 505 milliseconds

Comment: Yes...i too tried radio button scenarios in different pages and they worked fine..but i don't understand what is the issue in this page...Before selecting radio button i need to enter email address in text box..upto there everything is automated fine

Comment: yeah..i will check

Comment: again error..
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for element to be clickable: [[FirefoxDriver: firefox on WINDOWS (cb4f1016-458c-40fb-9b1a-0ef7885272ed)] -> xpath: //input[@id='passwordRadios1']] (tried for 7 second(s) with 500 MILLISECONDS interval)
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: '5234b32', time: '2017-03-10 09:00:17 -0800'

Comment: Alright then can you be able to update your hrml code.. Like i want full page of your html code. i can able to relocate the exact error.

Comment: how can i edit my question again..where can i find that option?

Comment: Click on `edit` button blow the question `tag name`, update your `html` code.

Comment: Now i am not able see any elements.

Comment: After updating your html, i have try the above code, and it gets run successfully.

Comment: but i want to know why am failing to select radio button if we select checkboxes in previous page

Comment: because when you move to the next page you were not providing any `wait`. So element not found exception was throwing. So here i provided wait so your page will be loaded first and then find to the element.

Answer (score 0):

Try using JavascriptExecutor to click on the element as below:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='passwordRadios2']"));
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

Comment: I guess this might will help you, put some `wait` and try to click element with java-script executor method.

Comment: Yeah using this  java-script executor method able to select radio button only if i did not select giftbox and gift_message checkboxes in previous page(sample page).By selecting those checkboxes and continuing to login page radio button is not clickable

Comment: Use some wait and then try or also try using explicit wait.